# Calculate Fourier series and prove uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, uniform-convergence

here is an exercice I'm struggling with so if anyone can help it would be highly appreciated .

Let $f\; : \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a $2\pi$ periodic function define over $\left[-\pi,\pi \right] $ with :

> $f(x)=\begin{cases}
> x & \text{ if } x\in  \left[0,\frac{\pi}{2} \right]\\ 
>  \pi - x& \text{ if }x \in\left[\frac{\pi}{2},\pi \right]  \\ 
>  -f(-x)& \text{ if } x\in \left[-\pi,0 \right] 
> \end{cases}$

I know that the Fourier series of a function $f(x)$ is a series on the form
$${1\over 2}a_0 +\sum_{n=1}^\infty \bigl(a_n \cos(nx) + b_n \sin(nx)\bigr)$$

where the coefficients $a_n$ and $b_n$ are given by :

$a_n ={1\over\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\cos(nx)\,{\rm d}x\qquad$

$b_n ={1\over\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\sin(nx){\rm d}x\qquad$

but I have some trouble computing due to how $f$ is define .. and how can I prove that it will converge uniformly to the original function $f$ .

if  anyone could help thanks in advance

Comment: Well, that looks like an odd extension of a functions...and it is thus an odd function so $\;a_n=0\;$ and you thus get a cosines series.

Comment: split the integral up into the various different parts of $[-\pi, \pi]$, then compute the integrals using integration by parts differentiating the linear term and integating the cosine/sine.

For the $[-\pi, 0]$ section of the integral, taking the substitute $u=-x$ means you can transform it back to an integral over $[0,\pi]$.

Comment: And you get a **sines** series, of course. This is for the first comment above.

Comment: Alright , thank you guys , and how do I proceed for the uniform convergence ?

Comment: Perhaps you can use the fact that $f$ is Lipschitz continuous?

Comment: If the Fourier series of a continuous function is absolutely convergent then the Fourier series converges uniformly to the original function.